# Mismatched input antlr4 misinterpreting

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I got stuck with my compilerproject for university and have trouble parsing the following input

```
haupt() {
    while(i==2) {
        (5+2)*3
        }
}
```

with this grammar:

```
grammar Demo;

@header {
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
}

program:
    functionList
    ;

functionList:
    function*
    ;

function:
    'haupt()' '{' stmntList '}'                 #haupt
    |'Integer' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'   #integerFunction
    | 'String' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'   #stringFunction
    | 'void' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'     #voidFunction
    ;

paramList:
    param (',' paramList)?
    ;

param:
    'Integer' ID                                        
    | 'String' ID                                       
    ;

variableList:
    ID (',' variableList)?
    ;


stmntList:
    stmnt (stmntList)?                                      
    ;

stmnt:
    'Integer' ID ';'                                                        #integerStmnt
    | 'String' ID   ';'                                                     #stringStmnt
    |  ID '=' expr  ';'                                                     #varAssignment
    | 'print''(' ID ')'     ';'                                             #printText
    | 'toString' '(' ID ')'';'                                              #convertString
    | 'toInteger''('ID')'';'                                                #convertInteger
    | 'if' '(' boolExpr ')' '{' stmntList '}'  ('else' '{' stmntList '}')?  #elseStmnt  
    | 'for' '(' ID '=' expr ',' boolExpr ',' stmnt ')' '{' stmntList '}'    #forLoop    
    | 'while' '(' boolExpr ')' '{' stmntList '}'                            #whileLoop
    | 'do' '{' stmntList '}' 'while' '(' boolExpr ')'   ';'                 #doWhile
    | 'return' expr             ';'                                         #returnVar
    | ID '(' variableList ')'';'                                            #functionCall               
    ;

boolExpr:
    boolParts ('&&' boolExpr)?                  #logicAnd
    | boolParts ('||' boolExpr)?                #logicOr
    ;

boolParts:
    expr '==' expr                      #isEqual
    | expr '!=' expr                    #isUnequal
    | expr '>' expr                     #biggerThan
    | expr '<' expr                     #smallerThan
    | expr '>=' expr                    #biggerEqual
    | expr '<=' expr                    #smallerEqual
    ;

expr:
    links=expr '+' rechts=product                   #addi
    | links = expr '-' rechts=product               #diff
    |product                            #prod
    ;

product:
    links=product '*' rechts=factor                 #mult
    | links=product '/' rechts=factor               #teil
    | factor                            #fact
    ;

factor:
    '(' expr')'                         #bracket
    | ID                                #var
    | zahl=NUMBER                           #numb
    ;


ID  :       [a-zA-Z]*;
NUMBER  :   '0'|[1-9][0-9]*;
WS:         [\r\n\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

Because I get the following error message:

```
line 1:5: mismatched input '(' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '*', '+', '/'}
```

I think that antlr misinterprets the input and thinks that "haupt" is an ID instead of the first rule of function. How can this happen? I always thought antlr uses the first rule matching?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if that is your problem, but I have never actually seen a grammar before where parenthesis were part of a keyword, as in `haupt()` while also being allowed elsewhere as separate tokens. Maybe try 'haupt' '(' ')' instead of 'haupt()'?

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'haupt' '(' ')' as suggested but 'haupt()' should match. In fact it does. The error I get is on line 3. Nothing in statement matches (5+2)*3.

Answer (score 0):

I get a different error:

```
line 3:8 no viable alternative at input '('
```

which I can explain: (5+2)*3 is no statement (as Ter already pointed out).

You seem to use an odd version of ANTLR...

You should also watch out for the warnings:

```
warning(146): Path\To\File\Demo.g4:95:0: non-fragment lexer rule 'ID' can match the empty string
```

This tells you that the empty string would also be an identifier (which is not what you want in most cases). Changing the `*` to a `+` helps...

Comment: Tried this, nevertheless the ID didn't seem to have caused the problem. Anyone another idea why ANTLR uses the #functioncall and not the #printText rule of stmnt?

Comment: There is no print in your posted example.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647551/mismatched-input-antlr4-misinterpreting/22839259?noredirect=1#comment35304391_22839259):

It works fine for me (note that the ID rule has been slightly changed from your version but it also works with your version).

If you take a look at the token types (the numbers in `<>`), you'll see that the types for `print` and `abc` (i.e. an `ID`) are different (17(`'print'`) and 33(`ID`)).

grammar:

```
grammar Demo;

@header {
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
}

program:
    functionList
    ;

functionList:
    function*
    ;

function:
    'haupt()' '{' stmntList '}'                 #haupt
    |'Integer' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'   #integerFunction
    | 'String' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'   #stringFunction
    | 'void' ID '(' paramList ')' '{' stmntList '}'     #voidFunction
    ;

paramList:
    param (',' paramList)?
    ;

param:
    'Integer' ID
    | 'String' ID
    ;

variableList:
    ID (',' variableList)?
    ;


stmntList:
    stmnt (stmntList)?
    ;

stmnt:
    'Integer' ID ';'                                                        #integerStmnt
    | 'String' ID   ';'                                                     #stringStmnt
    |  ID '=' expr  ';'                                                     #varAssignment
    | 'print''(' ID ')'     ';'                                             #printText
    | 'toString' '(' ID ')'';'                                              #convertString
    | 'toInteger''('ID')'';'                                                #convertInteger
    | 'if' '(' boolExpr ')' '{' stmntList '}'  ('else' '{' stmntList '}')?  #elseStmnt
    | 'for' '(' ID '=' expr ',' boolExpr ',' stmnt ')' '{' stmntList '}'    #forLoop
    | 'while' '(' boolExpr ')' '{' stmntList '}'                            #whileLoop
    | 'do' '{' stmntList '}' 'while' '(' boolExpr ')'   ';'                 #doWhile
    | 'return' expr             ';'                                         #returnVar
    | ID '(' variableList ')'';'                                            #functionCall
    ;

boolExpr:
    boolParts ('&&' boolExpr)?                  #logicAnd
    | boolParts ('||' boolExpr)?                #logicOr
    ;

boolParts:
    expr '==' expr                      #isEqual
    | expr '!=' expr                    #isUnequal
    | expr '>' expr                     #biggerThan
    | expr '<' expr                     #smallerThan
    | expr '>=' expr                    #biggerEqual
    | expr '<=' expr                    #smallerEqual
    ;

expr:
    links=expr '+' rechts=product                   #addi
    | links = expr '-' rechts=product               #diff
    |product                            #prod
    ;

product:
    links=product '*' rechts=factor                 #mult
    | links=product '/' rechts=factor               #teil
    | factor                            #fact
    ;

factor:
    '(' expr')'                         #bracket
    | ID                                #var
    | zahl=NUMBER                           #numb
    ;


ID  :       [a-zA-Z]+;
NUMBER  :   '0'|[1-9][0-9]*;
WS:         [\r\n\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

test file:

```
haupt() {
    while(i==2) {
        print(abc);
        }
}
```

result:

```
[@0,0:6='haupt()',<18>,1:0]
[@1,8:8='{',<9>,1:8]
[@2,14:18='while',<6>,2:4]
[@3,19:19='(',<20>,2:9]
[@4,20:20='i',<33>,2:10]
[@5,21:22='==',<25>,2:11]
[@6,23:23='2',<34>,2:13]
[@7,24:24=')',<30>,2:14]
[@8,26:26='{',<9>,2:16]
[@9,36:40='print',<17>,3:8]
[@10,41:41='(',<20>,3:13]
[@11,42:44='abc',<33>,3:14]
[@12,45:45=')',<30>,3:17]
[@13,46:46=';',<7>,3:18]
[@14,56:56='}',<13>,4:8]
[@15,58:58='}',<13>,5:0]
[@16,59:58='<EOF>',<-1>,5:1]
(program (functionList (function haupt() { (stmntList (stmnt while ( (boolExpr (boolParts (expr (product (factor i))) == (expr (product (factor 2))))) ) { (stmntList (stmnt print ( abc ) ;)) })) })))
```

[image: Parse tree]